# Delete entire row (document) in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to delete the entire row (document) in a AWS dynamoDB table via the cli?

From what I can tell, I can only delete a single item per delete. How can I delete the entire row with all the items in it?

Comment: An item is a collection of attributes. RDBMS users would call these rows and columns. Also, see https://www.dynamodbguide.com/anatomy-of-an-item/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DynamoDB "row" is a single "item". Everything is stored by its Partition and optional Sort key. Those are the keys you use in the delete operation. So when you do a delete you are deleting the "item" or "row" that has that key, in its entirety.